# Catch Windows Messages in VSTO Plug-In

Tags: c#, vsto

Is there a way to catch windows messages within word (I tried overriding WinProc… no go)? I have a word VSTO plug-in that I’m trying to communicate with externally… ideally I would like to post a message from one application, catch that message in word, and then perform the appropriate response…

Comment: sorry, not really aware on how this thing works. i'll look at my past questions/messages and see what i can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding interprocess communication in Word (which is a mess when it comes to privileges with UAC) I came up with my own solution:

I set up a hook within my instance of my word VSTO plugin with SetWinEventHook() (hooking SYS_ALERT) … I simply monitor new windows created (OB_CREATE), if it’s an application that uses the explained camera then I close the currently running graph in DS, freeing the camera and allowing it to be used in the application that has focus. Each of my programs that use the camera will implement this class hook.

Better ideas welcome…

Answer (score 2):

Since this functionality isn't exposed by the interop assemblies I would not suggest this method. You should only try and interact with office applications through these APIs.

If you just need interprocess communication and you have control over the sender and receiver I would suggest using a socket connection or a pipe. Word is going to to be handling it's own windows messages, and it would not be a good idea to interfere with that process.

Comment: i've though of named pipes, it's just a tad more complex than the simple approach of overriding WinProc in winforms.... Named pipes can be a mess and cause more problems than what its worth....

Comment: The scenario is I have 4 applications which use a webcam… this device is aloud 1 instance in directshow. So if a customer was to use 2 at the same time i need a way to communicate with the application that has a running graph, tell it to close the handle to the camera and allow it to start in another application